# How do I generate an answer key with the HTML shown below?

Tags: xslt

I need to generate an HTML answer key using XSLT from these HTML questions into a separate HTML page.

This is my HTML of two questions with answer choices and the correct answer marked with the `typeof="ktp:AnswerCorrect"`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" data-uuid="4a02f4203652478eaa5bbeaec6b1634b" enumeration="1.3" designation="Lesson">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <link href="../../assets/css/main.css" title="default" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <title>Backsolving</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<section typeof="ktp:Section" class="ktp-section">
            <ol property="ktp:questionSet" typeof="ktp:QuestionSet" class="ktp-question-set counter-reset-10">
                <li property="ktp:question" typeof="ktp:Question" class="ktp-question">
                    <p class="qtype-prepare">The product of two consecutive positive integers is 156. What is the greater of the two integers? </p>
                    <ol class="ktp-answer-set list-upper-alpha">
                        <li property="ktp:answer" typeof="ktp:Answer">11</li>
                        <li property="ktp:answer" typeof="ktp:Answer">12</li>
                        <li property="ktp:answer" typeof="ktp:AnswerCorrect">13</li>
                        <li property="ktp:answer" typeof="ktp:Answer">14</li>
                        <li property="ktp:answer" typeof="ktp:Answer">15</li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </section>
       
        <div class="Practice">
            <section typeof="ktp:Section" class="ktp-section">
                <ol property="ktp:questionSet" typeof="ktp:QuestionSet" class="ktp-question-set counter-reset-11">
                    <li property="ktp:question" typeof="ktp:Question" class="ktp-question">
                        <p class="qtype-practice">The surface area of a cube with side length (<i>x</i> + 4) is 294. What is the value of <i>x</i>?</p>
                        <ol class="ktp-answer-set list-upper-alpha">
                            <li property="ktp:answer" typeof="ktp:Answer">−10</li>
                            <li property="ktp:answer" typeof="ktp:Answer">−1</li>
                            <li property="ktp:answer" typeof="ktp:Answer">3</li>
                            <li property="ktp:answer" typeof="ktp:AnswerCorrect">7</li>
                            <li property="ktp:answer" typeof="ktp:Answer">19</li>
                        </ol>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </section>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The output needs to look something like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    enumeration="1.3" designation="Lesson">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link href="../../assets/css/main.css" title="default" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <title>Answer Key</title>
    </head>
    <body><section class="output"></section><section
            class="unit-info"></section><section
            class="answer-key">
            <h1>Answer Key</h1>
            <ol class="list-decimal">
                <li class="ktp-question counter-reset-10"
                   ><b>C</b></li>
                <li class="ktp-question"><b>D</b></li>
            </ol>
        </section></body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure where to start building an XSLT script to make this happen. Any help would be most appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your input file needs to be valid XML. In your source you miss the root tag. It could be <questions> ... </questions>

Comment: My input file is HTML as well. I added the HTML beginning and ending code.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is the difference both answer's class, but here is a stylesheet that should return close to what you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ktp="http://ktp" xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
        <html enumeration="1.3" designation="Lesson">
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8" />
                <link href="../../assets/css/main.css" title="default" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
                <title>Answer Key</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                        <section class="output"></section><section
                                class="unit-info"></section><section
                                class="answer-key">
                        <h1>Answer Key</h1>
                        <ol class="list-decimal">
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="//h:ol[h:li/@property = 'ktp:answer']"/>

                        </ol>
                </section>
            </body>
        </html>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="h:ol">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="h:li"/>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="h:li">
        <xsl:if test="@typeof = 'ktp:AnswerCorrect'">
                <li class="ktp-question"><b><xsl:value-of select="substring('ABCDEFGH',position(),1)"/></b></li>
            </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It returns:

```
~/xslt$ xalan -xsl to-answer.xsl -in source.xml
<html xmlns:ktp="http://ktp" xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" enumeration="1.3" designation="Lesson">
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="../../assets/css/main.css" title="default" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title>Answer Key</title>
</head>
<body>
<section class="output"></section>
<section class="unit-info"></section>
<section class="answer-key">
<h1>Answer Key</h1>
<ol class="list-decimal">
<li class="ktp-question">
<b>C</b>
</li>
<li class="ktp-question">
<b>D</b>
</li>
</ol>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```